# What does the pottery mark on the bottom of this purple sand clay teapot say? I picked it up recently and can't do it myself

Tags: translation

[image][image]

I do appreciate any insight on this. It is so hard for me to do this myself.

Comment: “蔣偉明制”  made (制) by a person surnamed “蔣” & named “偉明”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font style: Traditional Square Seal Script.

Meaning: Made by Jiang Weiming.

Jiang is the family name, Wei Ming is the first name.

If the purple clay pot is genuine, it is very precious.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer. The teapot has all the indicators of it being genuine. Occasional white spots,  black bumps, and indents on the surface.  It is quite the beautiful teapot. I just have a terrible time converting the marks to Chinese text.